# Creating C# Type from full name

Tags: c#, assemblies, types

I'm trying to get a Type object from type full name i'm doing the folowing:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();  
string toNativeTypeName="any type full name";
Type t = asm.GetType(toNativeTypeName);
```

I get null, why?

the assembly is my executable (.net executable) and the type name is: System.Xml.XmlNode

Comment: Show us what you mean by a full name?

Comment: the assembly is my executable (.net executable) and the type name is: System.Xml.XmlNode

Comment: System.Xml.XmlNode will not exist in your assembly so you should use Type.GetType inestead of Assembly.GetType.

Comment: System.Xml.XmlNode is in System.Xml(.dll), not in your assembly. You are probably just referencing this assembly.

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to use the fully qualified name to get an XmlNode.

Comment: You get null because the type does not exist in that assembly. With how little details you give, it's likely one of your assumptions is wrong. A more elaborate question would allow answers and revelations to that.

Answer (score 32):

Well, if that really is the type's full name (i.e. including namespace) and it's in that assembly, then it should work. Could you give an example where it doesn't? As you're using `Assembly.GetType` rather than `Type.GetType` you *shouldn't* include the assembly name in the type name.

Note that the name for a generic type isn't what you might expect it to be. For instance, you'd use:

```
assembly.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1");
```

to get the generic list type, then use `Type.MakeGenericType` to provide type arguments.

Of course, that's only relevant when the type is generic. If that's not the problem, I'd double check that the type really is in your entry assembly.

EDIT: Oh, and be aware that nested types will be "Container+Nested" rather than "Container.Nested" if that's relevant...

Comment: the assembly is my executable (.net executable) and the type name is: System.Xml.XmlNode

Comment: Then that's the problem: System.Xml.XmlNode isn't a type within your assembly, is it? You'll need to either use the right assembly, or call Type.GetType with the full assembly information.

Comment: @JonSkeet What if you don't know what assembly the type is in. Is there anyway to search all assemblies currently loaded?

Comment: @Xaade, you can get all assemblies loaded by : `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.

Answer (score 11):

See my suggestion below, only looping business namespace for speed

```
private static Type GetBusinessEntityType(string typeName)
{
    Debug.Assert(typeName != null);

    List<System.Reflection.Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("AF.BusinessEntities")).ToList();

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        Type t = assembly.GetType(typeName, false);
        if (t != null)
            return t;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(
        "Type " + typeName + " doesn't exist in the current app domain");
}
```

Here's another way to do it:

```
Type t = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType("the.type", true, false);
```

Use reflector to see how it's done, at least for fun :)

Comment: The `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager` did it for me, the otherone I didn't get it to work for a Enum: `NLibrary+Modules`

Answer (score 8):

Your type name is most probably wrong. If you create a reference to the type in code and then check its `Type.FullName` property you will see how the name of the type should look.

Also you could try the `Type.GetType` method and see what it returns. Maybe your type isn't in that assembly at all?

UPDATE – use `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`:

It turns out that I was wrong about using the `Type.FullName` property. If you use the `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` property you will get the fully qualified name that can be used by `Type.GetType`.

For `System.Xml.XmlNode` you get the following name: `System.Xml.XmlElement, System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

Answer (score 8):

why you are defining assembly to use get type!, also you need to put namespace

```
string toNativeTypeName = "System.Int32";
Type t = Type.GetType(toNativeTypeName );
MessageBox.Show(t.FullName);
```

Comment: If you know that the type *is* in the entry assembly, then using Assembly.GetType with the name including the namespace but *not* the assembly name can be an awful lot easier than including the full assembly name including version...

Comment: This helped me. I was trying to pull serialized messages off of a queue. I was testing with System.String and not finding it while looping through all of the assemblies from current domain. When I change to use Type.GetType, it just worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this thread and noticed that the original question has not quite been answered.  I could be wrong, but in reading the question I think the authors intent was to be able to simply get a Type from an Assembly that is referenced or part of your application.

Here's what I did to solve that problem.

```
public static Type GetTypeFromFullName(string fullClassName)
{
    AssemblyPartCollection parts = Deployment.Current.Parts;

    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        Uri resUri = new Uri(part.Source, UriKind.Relative);
        Stream resStream = Application.GetResourceStream(resUri).Stream;
        Assembly resAssembly = part.Load(resStream);
        Type tryType = resAssembly.GetType(fullClassName, false);
        if (tryType != null)
            return tryType;
    }

    return null;
}
```