# How to Cast string to be the Enum-Tag value in C# ( to be The Enum Name )?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast  a String to an Enum Tag in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782170/cast-a-string-to-an-enum-tag-in-c)

How to convert a string which have a name of existing enum-TAG (have name of Enum Title) 
to  become of type of Enum

Not to become one of the Enum listed variables values,
But to be the Enum-Tag name  which is of type Enum?

For instance, I might have

```
Enum MyEnum { A,B,C,D };
```

and then

```
String a = "MyEnum";
```

Comment: This question seems popular today - what is going on?

Comment: I think you want to turn a simple type-name into a System.Type? This is difficult to do *reliably* without more information available than just the simple name. Do you know the assembly the type is in? Do you have the assembly-qualified name or at least the fully-qualified type name? Anyway, this should get you started: Creating C# Type from full name.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392763/creating-c-type-from-full-name

Comment: This was closed too hastily; I believe the OP wants something different from what is in the "duplicate".

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse it as Enum using Enum.Parse:

```
myEnum result = (myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), stringToConvert);
```

There is a couple of elements to consider here. First of all the Enum.Parse takes the *type* of the target Enum. Second is it only returns type *object* so you need to manually convert it to the correct enum type.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyEnum value = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "myname");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum e = (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum), "A", true);
```

this should do it